# Upper bound of number of different rows for a binary matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Let $\mathcal{X} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a measurable space, Fix $m,q \in \mathbb{N}^*$, (the $m$ $x_i$'s are i.i.d and follow distribution $\mathcal{D}$)

and $X = (x_1, \dots, x_m) \sim \mathcal{D}_{\mathcal{X}}^m$.

Consider a finite set of functions $\mathcal{F} = \Big \{ h_1, \dots h_q \Big\}$ that takes the values:$\{-1,1\}$

We are interested in the following set:

$$\mathcal{F}(X) = \Big\{(h_1(x_i), \dots h_q(x_i)), i \in [m]\Big\}$$

such that at least two elements of $\mathcal{F}$ disagree on $X$ (disagree on all samples $x_1, \dots, x_m$): That is :

$$\forall l \in [m], \exists i \neq j \in [q]: h_i(x_l) \neq h_j(x_l)$$

I'm interested in the two following questions :

1- what is a tight upper bound on $|\mathcal{F}(X)|$?

2- what can we say about $\mathbb{E}[|\mathcal{F}(X)|]$?

**EDIT:**

Previously (before the edit), I represented $\mathcal{F}(X)$ in the matrix form by where each row represents a vector belonging to $\mathcal{F}(X)$,so it can be seen as:

$$
\mathcal{F}(X) = \begin{pmatrix} 
    h_1(x_1) & h_2(x_1)&  \cdots & h_q(x_1) \\
    h_1(x_2) & h_2(x_2)&  \cdots & h_q(x_2) \\
    \vdots & \cdots & \cdots & \vdots \\
    h_1(x_m) & h_2(x_m) &    \cdots    & h_q(x_m) 
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Counting elements of $\mathcal{F}(X)$ is equivalent to counting different rows in the matrix representation.

Comment: You could just have a 2-column matrix with as many rows as you want where each row is (1, -1) or (1, -1), so I think you are missing some constraints from the question.

Comment: Also, for "expectation" to make sense, there should be some randomness in the construction, but I did not see any.

Comment: @GordonRoyle counting rows means counting vectors, if you repeat your row n times doesn't mean your count would increase, I'm interested in the cardinal different rows (different vectors) .

Comment: @JukkaKohonen all elements of the matrix are generated randomly by some distribution D.

Comment: rivana, when you need to clarify a question you should edit the original so that everyone doesn't have to read all the comments. "number of rows" is not the same as "number of different rows". It seems the answer to Q1 is $2^m-2$ and your example shows only 6 possibilities and not $2^3=8$.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay the answer is 8 because * takes two values -1 and 1.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay I am editing.

Comment: You wrote 3 rows with 2 cases each, which makes 6 cases. Where do you get 8 from?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay, the number of different possible rows is 8, I'm interested in counting all possible different rows. I edited the problem, and explained this confusion which is related to the matrix representation.

Comment: Has the requirement for at least one $+1$ and at least one $-1$ gone now?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay, yes it remains I forgot to add it in the edit, now it's done, thanks!

Comment: Where are the functions $f_i$ defined? How are $h_i$ related to them? What exactly is $\mathcal{F}(X)$: is it the multiset of rows of the $q\times m$ matrix $(f_i(x_j))$? What do you mean by expectation: the functions $f_1,\ldots,f_q$ are fixed and $x_i$ are i.i.d. in $\mathcal{X}$ (then probably $\mathcal{X}$ is not only measurable, but probability space)?

Comment: I see that you changed the meaning of $m$ in the last few edits. I can't think of any interpretation of the question for which the answer to Q1 is 8 in the case of $q=3$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov, the $f_i$s are the $h_i$'s it was just a typo mistake.

Comment: @FedorPetrov you can ignore the matrix interpretation, that's just to have some idea of the values of the vectors, ignore the EDIT part please.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay, indeed it's 6 not 8, you're right, thanks!

Comment: So the answer to Q1 is $\min\{m,2^q-2\}$ and this is obvious. As Fedor noted, Q2 is not sufficiently defined for an answer to be possible.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay thank you for your answer, I don't understand your and Fedor's remark about  insufficient conditions for a possible answer, we are interested in the quantity $\underset{X \sim  \mathcal{D}_{\mathcal{X}}^m}{\mathbb{E}}[|\mathcal{F}(X)|] $  the randomness is over $X$, am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know what $\cal D$ means, nor what $\chi$ is, nor ${\cal D}^m_{\chi}$, nor $\sim{\cal D}^m_{\chi}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson $X$ contains m random variables $x_1, \dots, x_m$ that are i.i.d and follow some unknown distirbution $\mathcal{D}$